# R - NAs for specific hours on hourly time series

Tags: r, time-series

EDIT: I ran into an additional issue and hence edit the question: 
After aggregating the hourly data to a daily average on one hand and filtering for 1 data point (at 16:00) every day on the other hand, I have the same number of data points (1 every day). However, since I want to concatinate the data frames, I wont have equally many lines if I run the code before I get my data point at 16:00. Hence I was thinking to add a line (with date and NA value) if there is no data point available yet. I add the code, then it should make sense.

```
is.installed <- function(mypkg){
  is.element(mypkg, installed.packages()[,1])
} 
if (!is.installed("ggplot2")){
  install.packages("ggplot2")
}
if (!is.installed("lubridate")){
  install.packages("lubridate")
}
if (!is.installed("openxlsx")){
  install.packages("openxlsx")
}
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(openxlsx)


Storico_G <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

Storico_G1 <- read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "http://www.snamretegas.it/repository/file/Info-storiche-qta-gas-trasportato/dati_operativi/2017/DatiOperativi_2017-IT.xlsx",sheet = "Storico_G+1", startRow = 1, colNames = TRUE)

# Selecting Column C,E,R from Storico_G and stored in variable Storico_G_df
# Selecting Column A,P from Storico_G+1 and stored in variable Storico_G1_df

Storico_G_df <- data.frame(Storico_G$pubblicazione,Storico_G$IMMESSO, Storico_G$`RICONSEGNATO.(1)`, Storico_G$BILANCIAMENTO.RESIDUALE )
Storico_G1_df <- data.frame(Storico_G1$pubblicazione, Storico_G1$`SBILANCIAMENTO.ATTESO.DEL.SISTEMA.(SAS)`)


# Conerting pubblicazione in date format and time
Storico_G_df$pubblicazione <- ymd_h(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione)
Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione   <- ymd_h(Storico_G1_df$Storico_G1.pubblicazione)


# Selecting on row which is having 4PM value in Storico_G+1 excel sheet tab
Storico_G1_df <- subset(Storico_G1_df, hour(Storico_G1_df$pubblicazione) == 16)
rownames(Storico_G1_df) <- 1:nrow(Storico_G1_df)

# Averaging hourly values to 1 daily data point in G excel sheet tab
Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione <- strptime(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%Y_%m_%d_%H")
storico_G_df_agg <- aggregate(Storico_G_df, by=list(day=format(Storico_G_df$Storico_G.pubblicazione, "%F")), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

INITIAL QUESTION: I struggle with the following: I have an hourly time series, which already contains NAs at specific hours. Anyway, I decided to also assign NAs to every value other than at 16:00. Basically, I only want to use one data print, but still keep the time stamps because I need to plot alongside normal hourly data (24 data points a day available.

Alternatively, I could plot the daily average of the complete data alongside the data point at 16:00 every day to ensure alignment. That would obviously imply creating the daily average for the complete time series and filter only for the data point at 16:00 every day.

Greatly appreciate any help how I can resolve my little dilemma.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not work with the package `xlsx`, so I can't work with your actual data. Here's a reproducible examle with fake data.

```
d <- data.frame(time=paste0("2017_07_",rep(10:15, each=24),"_", 
                            formatC(0:23, flag="0", width=2)),
                value=cumsum(rnorm(24*6))  )

d$time <- strptime(d$time, "%Y_%m_%d_%H")

dagg <- aggregate(d, by=list(day=format(d$time, "%F")), FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)[,-2]
dagg$day <- strptime(dagg$day, format="%F")

plot(d, type="l", las=1)
lines(dagg, col=2)
```

Also, your data seems messed up, check out for example these timestamps:

```
2017_07_04_21
2017_07_04_22
2017_07_04_23
2017_07_04_00 <-- day 05?
2017_07_04_01
2017_07_04_02
2017_07_04_03
2017_07_04_04
2017_07_04_05
2017_07_05_06
2017_07_05_07
```

Comment: Hi berry, thank you very much! I used OPENXLSX, sorry should have added that. need to have a look at time stamps.. cheers